# How can I detect drags in the status bar and navigation bar?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, scrollview

I have a ScrollView which I want to start scrolling when the dragged view is above or below the ScrollView. This means I need to know the drag coordinates even over the status bar and navigation bar. I have tried with this:

```
getWindow().getDecorView.setonDragListener(...)
```

but this does not include the status bar and navigation bar.

Is there a way to figure out the drag coordinates globally within that activity?

Is there an easier way to scroll the ScrollView when the dragged view is just above or below the ScrollView?

The images below show that the Drag and Drop framework allows you to drag over the status and navigation bars... which is where I think I will need detection.

[image]

[image]